# Can I know the number of tasks awaiting execution in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, threadpool

I am using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor:

```
threadPoolEx = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(limit);
```

I want to know the number of tasks awaiting execution, or just to know if there are any tasks waiting (not necessarily the number).

How can I do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` has a `getQueue()` method that you can use. You can query that for various bits of info on the waiting tasks (e.g. `getQueue().getSize()`).